# How to burst a report in report studio on a particular day for a particular customer

Tags: cognos

The customer's name and email address is stored in a burst table in my database .

Burst table:

[image]

I want the report of joe to be bursted on friday at 10.00 am ..

How to implement this in cognos report studio.

Comment: Hey I need a quick help dear friends ... :(

Comment: Most people who ask here do.

Answer (score 1):

Report bursting and scheduling are different concepts altogether.

You can't combine different schedules within a single burst schedule. if you need to burst reports at different timings then you'll have use different schedules rather than combining them into single burst.

you can maintain burst table with schedule info and filter it based on the schedule. for eg. say customer joe wants reports at 10 AM; have 10 AM as schedule info and bucket all the users with 10 AM and run them in single burst. you might need to have different schedule based on the requirements of users.